# ¿Por qué al poner los caracteres 0 y 1 en un vector me salen caracteres especiales? [C++]

Tags: c++, array, string, ascii

Estabá tratando de crear un script que leyera numeros decimales y que los convirtiera en binario almacenandolos en un vector con la libreria `<vector>`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int binary, cifra;
vector <char> result;
string arr = "01";

while(1)
{
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero entero: "; cin>>binary;

    do
    {
        cifra = binary % 2; //Resto de 2
        binary /= 2;
        
        if(cifra == 1)
            result.push_back(arr[1]);
        else
            result.push_back(arr[0]);
    } while(binary > 2);
    
    cout << "El resultado es: ";
    for ( vector<char>::const_iterator i = result.end();    i != result.begin();    --i )
        std::cout << *i ;
    
    result.clear();
    cout <<"\n"<< endl;
   }
}
```

El problema es que por alguna razon al principio de la secuencia según el numero que se ingresa **aparecen caracteres ASCII**;

Al ingresar `128` me devuelve `►00000`

Al ingresar `217` me devuelve `☻101100`

Especificamente cualquier número que escriba siempre sale al principio el caracter 02 o el 16.

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muy sencillo: porque, [según su documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end), `end( )`:

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the vector.

Es decir, `end( )` devuelve un iterador que apunta **al siguiente después del último**, no al último como tú lo estás interpretando.

¿ Y que hay en el *siguiente después del último* ? Pues vete a saber. Es un valor sin inicializar, por lo que puede tener cualquier contenido arbitrario y aleatorio.

En lugar de `begin( )` y `end( )`, **deberías** usar `rbegin( )` y `rend( )`, que están pensadas justamente para lo que tu pretendes: recorrer un `vector< >` **desde el final hasta el principio**:

```
for( vector<char>::const_iterator i = result.rbegin(); i != result.rend(); ++i )
```

Si insistes en usar `begin( )` y `end( )`, pues tendrás que cambiar un poco tu código:

```
vector< char >::const_iterator i;
for( i = result.end( ) - 1; i != result.begin( ); --i ) {
    cout << *i ;
    result.clear();
}
cout *i;
cout <<"\n"<< endl;
```

Comment: si pones casi todo en negrita, solo destaca lo que no está en negrita :P

Comment: @eferion ¡ jajajaja ! Me parece que he concentrado demasiado la respuesta ... ¡ Todo es importante ! xDD

Comment: @Trauma Muchas gracias :)